# Map $\mathbb{S}^{n} \to \mathbb{S}^n$ Passed to Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $f:\mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n \vee \mathbb{S}^n$ be the map by pinching $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ to a point and $g:\mathbb{S}^{n} \vee \mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n$ be the antipodal map. How can I show that in homology, $[\sigma] \mapsto ([\sigma],[\sigma]) \mapsto \sigma+H_n(g)\sigma$ by passing $g \circ f$ to homology?

I tried to consider the generator $\sigma=\Delta^n_1-\Delta^n_2$, where $\Delta_i^n$ are upper and lower hemisphere. The first map identifies the boundary of $\Delta^n_1$ and $\Delta^n_1$ as one point, but I have no idea why it is the same as $([\sigma],[\sigma])$.

Comment: It isn't clear what your $g$ is. You need to specify what function it is on both summands of the wedge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : Use that $H_n(S^n\vee S^n) \cong H_n(S^n)\oplus H_n(S^n)$, the isomorphism being induced by the projections $S^n\vee S^n\to S^n$ : then what does $S^n\to S^n\vee S^n\to S^n$ look like ?

Comment: Well, $g \circ \Delta^n_1$ is the boundary of $\Delta^n_1$ identified as the south pole, which is the sphere after pre-image of the projection map $q$ and similarly for $g \circ \Delta^n_2$. How is $q_*^{-1}[g_*\sigma]$ equal to $[\sigma]$?

Comment: Who is $q$ ? My hint was there to answer the first question, which is : why is $H_n(f) = ( [\sigma]\mapsto ([\sigma], [\sigma]))$

Comment: $q$ is the projection map you mentioned

Comment: Ok - note that there are two projections, $q_1$ and $q_2$ then - but then why would you want to look at $q_*^{-1}[g_*\sigma ]$ ? Note that $q_1\circ f$ and $q_2\circ f$ are both homotopic to the identity (they respectively consist in crushing down the bottom hemisphere and the top hemisphere, which are both contractible)

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.